# Asher Yatzar and bathroom doors

Tags: bathroom, asher-yatzar

Must one close the bathroom door before saying Asher Yatzar? Or May one say it even with it open? Assume for this case that you’d be facing the door (if that affects the answer at all.)

Comment: Even with the a closed door, sometimes an odor is felt even outside the bathroom.